# -event- can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have an event in a loop. I am trying to prevent the same method being added to an event more than once. I've implemented the `add` and `remove` accessors.

However, I get an error stating that:

`ItemsProcessed can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=`

When I try to call them, even within the same class.

```
ItemsProcessed(this, new EventArgs()); // Produces error

public event EventHandler ItemsProcessed
{
    add
    {
        ItemsProcessed -= value;
        ItemsProcessed += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        ItemsProcessed -= value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, it looks like you've created an infinite loop by accessing `ItemsProcessed` within the `ItemsProcessed` functions themselves.

Comment: For reference, the `EventName(args)` invoke trick only applies to *field-like events*, where some operations implicitly resolve to the *field* (not the event) within the class. I have to say "some", because the exact list changed between C# 3 and C# 4.

Answer (score 42):

With an explicit event, you need to provide your own backing store - either a delegate field or something like `EventHandlerList`. The current code is recursive. Try:

```
private EventHandler itemsProcessed;
public event EventHandler ItemsProcessed
{
    add
    {
        itemsProcessed-= value;
        itemsProcessed+= value;
    }

    remove
    {
        itemsProcessed-= value;
    }
}
```

Then (and noting I'm being a *little* cautious about the "about to turn `null`" edge-case re threading):

```
var snapshot = itemsProcessed;
if(snapshot != null) snapshot(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

With more recent C# versions, this can be simplified:

```
itemsProcessed?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Comment: One disadvantage: Only accessible within a class

Comment: Why would you want to access a private backing event outside of a class?

Comment: Subclassing, duh. Make stuff protected.

Comment: @Nyerguds subclassing rarely has a *good* reason to access backing fields; in the case of events, the more common approach is a `protected virtual void OnItemsProcessed() => itemsProcessed?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);` - job done, and no need to expose access to the field

Comment: Well I'm trying to make a custom `OnMouseWheel` that optionally executes the original linked `Control.MouseWheel` event... and I can't without also disabling the scrolling. Really frustrating. Mouse scroll is one of those weird semi-automatic things.

Answer (score 16):

I can't tell from your post if you are trying to raise the event from a derived class or not, but one thing I've found is that you can't define an event in a base class and then raise it (directly) in a derived class, for some reason that isn't real clear to me yet.

So I define protected functions in base classes to raise events (that are defined in those base classes), like this:

```
// The signature for a handler of the ProgressStarted event.
// title: The title/label for a progress dialog/bar.
// total: The max progress value.
public delegate void ProgressStartedType(string title, int total);

// Raised when progress on a potentially long running process is started.
public event ProgressStartedType ProgressStarted;

// Used from derived classes to raise ProgressStarted.
protected void RaiseProgressStarted(string title, int total) {
    if (ProgressStarted != null) ProgressStarted(title, total);
}
```

Then in the derived class, I call RaiseProgressStarted(title, total) instead of calling ProgressStarted(title, total).

It seems like kind of the long way around. Maybe someone else knows of a better way around this problem.

Comment: I just realized this is a 5 year old post. I came across the problem and figured out what was going on for me, so I posted this answer. Maybe it'll be helpful to someone.

Comment: Heh, I just had this problem again, couldn't quite remember what had caused it and how I'd fixed it, and found my own answer from 11 months ago. That's pretty funny.

Comment: it's 2019, this fixed my problem, thanks for the 2015 post on the 2010 question! :-D

Comment: I figured that this must be the case, and it solves the problem, but what I'd really like to know is the reason.  Perhaps this has become clear to someone in the past few years?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-raise-base-class-events-in-derived-classes

Answer (score 13):

It seems that if you implement the `EventHandler` explicitly, you can't refer to the 'Property' when firing the event. You must refer to the backing store.

Comment: You can't indeed. I was quite surprised by that!

Comment: This is the actual answer to the original question, but that issue wouldn't even make it past the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

What error? I guess its stack overflow error, because you are calling add and remove on yourserlf (same event). Also you cannot raise event ACCESSOR.

Valid way to do this is to create backing private event, that will be added and removed to from public accessor, and you should raise this private event.

Dang, minute late.

Comment: No, he doesn't know about the stack overflow because his code doesn't even compile.

Comment: Yeah, I stopped thinking about it when Marc's answer got posted.. you are right.