# Issue raising a simple event

Tags: c#, events, .net-4.0, raiseevent

My interface has an event that don't has an arguments

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
     event EventHandler OnSomethingHappened;
}
```

Here is how I am implementing it.

```
   public class MyBaseClass : IMyInterface
    {
private event EventHandler onSomethingHappened;
public event EventHandler OnSomethingHappened
{
    add
    {
        onSomethingHappened-= value;
        onSomethingHappened+= value;
    }

    remove
    {
        onSomethingHappened-= value;
    }
}
    }
```

But somehwere else when I try to use it as follows

```
if ( MyBaseClassInstance.OnSomethingHappened != null )
        MyBaseClassInstance.OnSomethingHappened();
```

I get following compilation error

> The event 'ConsoleApplication1.IMyInterface.OnSomethingHappened' can
>   only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `MyBaseClass` is **not** implementing `IMyInterface`. Regarding error, search for it, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4496799/1997232) is same problem.

Comment: thakns I tried doing that but continue to get same error.  Updated my question for changes I made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how your code might look:

```
    public interface IMyInterface
    {
        event EventHandler OnSomethingHappened;
    }

    //implement the interface
    public class MyBaseClass : IMyInterface
    {
        public event EventHandler OnSomethingHappened;

        public void DoSomeLogicWhichRaisesTheEvent()
        {
            if (OnSomethingHappened != null)
            {
                MyBaseClass sender = this;
                var eventArgs = new EventArgs();
                //let all subscibers to event know that the event happened
                OnSomethingHappened(sender, eventArgs);
            }
        }
    }

    public class ConsumerClass
    {
        private IMyInterface myBaseClassInstance;

        public ConsumerClass()
        {
            myBaseClassInstance = new MyBaseClass();
            //attach to the event
            myBaseClassInstance.OnSomethingHappened += MyBaseClassInstance_OnSomethingHappened;
        }

        private void MyBaseClassInstance_OnSomethingHappened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //react to the raised event
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

As you can see you need to implement the IMyInterface interface, and when MyBaseClass needs to raise the event you call OnSomethingHappened(sender, eventArgs);

ConsumerClass is where you need to consume, or to do something, as a reaction to the raised event.
You may consider to rename MyBaseClass to some other name, without 'Base' in it, because it is not an abstract class.

Comment: Could you explain briefly what's happening in this code and how that solves the problem?