# Why can´t we raise event with accessors?

Tags: c#, events

Why can´t we raise an event with a custom implementation, while it is possible without them? See this code:

```
public class Program
{
    private EventHandler myEvent;
    public event EventHandler MyEvent
    {
        add { myEvent += value; }
        remove { myEvent -= value; }
    }

    public event EventHandler AnotherEvent;

    public static void Main()
    {
        var target = new Program();
        target.MyEvent(null, null);       // ERROR CS0079
        target.AnotherEvent(null, null);  // compiles
    }
}
```

You see both events are declared within my class. While `target.AnotherEvent(...)` compiles just fine, `target.MyEvent(...)` does not:

> The Event MyEvent can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=.

I Know an event is just a delegate with an add- and remove-method. So `AnotherEvent` is translated by the compiler to an add- and a remove-method:

```
private EventHandler _AnotherEvent;
public event EventHandler AnotherEvent
{ 
    add { _AnotherEvent += value; }
    remove { _AnotherEvent -= value; }
}
```

So I assume the call to `AnotherEvent` is replaced by the compiler to a call to the private delegate, which was `_AnotherEvent(...)`.

Did I get this right? Are there any docs about why the second call works while the former does not? Or at least any description about what the compiler does here?

Comment: It works with `myEvent`. I guess because the `MyEvent` is a facade for the real event.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I already know that it works with `myEvent`. And I already **guessed** the same.

Comment: Don't know the details or specs, but I assume `add/remove` is not the same as `get/set`, it's rather translated to `void AddToInvocationList(delegate...);` and `void RemoveFromInvocationList(...);`, so the inner `EventHandler` field is not exposed to the consumer of the class.

Comment: @Adrian While the duplicate answers the part "what is the solution" (which was not even my question), it does not answer my question "**why** can we do the one but not the other".

Comment: The IL implementation of manual/auto add/remove is the same. But the invoke on the event is done on the field. So the public event is replace with a field and invoked on that field

Comment: @HimBromBeere Why? Do you mean this part of the spec? https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/classes.md#field-like-events

Comment: @HimBromBeere I agree with you, they might add this to the syntactic sugar, that the event is replaced on compile-time with a field. At the moment it looks inconsistent.

Comment: @Adrian Yeap, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's syntactical sugar. That you can call `AnotherEvent` like the backing field is a convenience provided by the compiler (`AnotherEvent` is a so-called *field-like event*). Once you add your own accessors, the event declaration ceases to be a field-like event and has to be invoked through its backing field.

See the relevant part of the [C# Language Specification](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/classes.md#field-like-events):

> **Field-like events**
>
> Within the program text of the class or struct that contains the declaration of an event, certain events can be used like fields. To be
>   used in this way, an event must not be abstract or extern, **and must
>   not explicitly include event_accessor_declarations.** Such an event can
>   be used in any context that permits a field. The field contains a
>   delegate (Delegates) which refers to the list of event handlers that
>   have been added to the event. If no event handlers have been added,
>   the field contains null.

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 4):

When an auto event is used `public event EventHandler AnotherEvent;`. The compiler will create a field (and some methods) for it and invoking is done on that field. So the `public event` does not exists anymore. It's syntactic sugar.

So invoking a non-auto event is not possible. Because it isn't found in the compiled code. It's replaced by `add_`, `remove_` methods. You can only invoke on the private field (which is generated)

This explains why you cannot invoke an event outside the class instance.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because there is simply now way to get the actual invokeable event handler. As you have noted, there is just an `add` and `remove`, not a `get`.

The generated code for the event handler is:

```
.event [mscorlib]System.EventHandler MyEvent
{
  .addon instance void ConsoleApp1.Program::add_MyEvent(class [mscorlib]System.EventHandler)
  .removeon instance void ConsoleApp1.Program::remove_MyEvent(class [mscorlib]System.EventHandler)
} // end of event Program::MyEvent
```

It adds two method references, one for `add` and one for `remove`. If you look at it, how would it know what method to invoke? What if `add` and `remove` are much more complex than they are now? There is just no way to know for sure what event handler to call.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you  lock the event before you add or remove a new event handler method.

saying that, have a look on this piece of code:

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent
{
    add
    {
        lock (objectLock)
        {
            myEvent += value;
        }
    }
    remove
    {
        lock (objectLock)
        {
            myEvent -= value;
        }
    }
}
```

The reason `public event EventHandler AnotherEvent;` works is because **When no custom event accessors are supplied in your code, the compiler will add them automatically.**

Follow this doc, [How to: Implement Custom Event Accessors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-implement-custom-event-accessors)  in order to get more details about the proper implementation and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496799/event-can-only-appear-on-the-left-hand-side-of-or) for another source.

Regarding the implementation:

```
 private EventHandler myEvent;
 public event EventHandler MyEvent
    {
        add
        {
            lock (objectLock)
            {
                myEvent += value;
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            lock (objectLock)
            {
                myEvent -= value;
            }
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler AnotherEvent;

    public static void Main()
    {
        var target = new Program();
        var myEvent =  target.MyEvent;
        myEvent?.Invoke(EventArgs.Empty, EventArgs.Empty);      
        target.AnotherEvent(null, null); 
    }
```

---

Edit to explain the implementation:

```
var myEvent =  target.MyEvent;
```

With an explicit event, you have to provide your own backing store - either a delegate field or something like `EventHandlerList`, so we just go with `var` here.

Comment: Out of the scope, what about singlethreaded applications? This is about syntactic sugar of C#, which replaces `event` declarations to methods and fields.

Comment: First I made changes to the code, just to notify :) Second, event with single threaded applications, it is always a good practice to lock your event handlers when dealing with delegates. It is an extra precaution to make sure everything will work properly.

Comment: This also means that you should lock it when invoking. Like lock/create a copy/unlock and execute. I'd rather not add/remove event handlers cross threading.

Comment: This is, as they like to say, to the eyes of the beholder :)