# The event 'control.mousemove' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

Please help me, I have the code:

```
this.panel1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(panel1.MouseMove);
```

But visual studio is giving me the error

> error The event 'control.mousemove' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Comment: `new MouseEventHandler(panel1_MouseMove);`  If you don't have a `panel1_MouseMove` method, you need to create one.

Comment: Does this answer your question [-event- can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496799/event-can-only-appear-on-the-left-hand-side-of-or) and or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756237/c-raising-an-inherited-event) answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is becaouse you have `pannel1.MouseMove` on the right hand side as well:

```
this.panel1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(panel1.MouseMove);
                                                  ^
                                                HERE
```

The correct way to create a handler is to provide method to the constructor you used, like:

```
this.panel1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(this.panel1_MouseMove);
```

where `panel1_MouseMove` is of the form:

```
private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
  // code here..
}
```

[See this for reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.mouseeventhandler?view=net-5.0).

Comment: This gives me the same error as if i do it this.panel1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(this.panel1.MouseMove);
But if i do this.panel1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(this.panel1_MouseMove);
Error CS1061 'Form1' does not contain a definition for 'panel1_MouseMove' and no accessible extension method 'panel1_MouseMove' accepting a first argument of type 'Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @NRGGAMING Then define method like I posted: `private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e){}`

Answer (score 0):

If your mousemove handler code is short, it can be neater to define it inline, like:

```
panel1.MouseMove += (sender, e) => {
  //handler code here, e.g. 
  this.Text = $"Mouse is at coords {e.Location}";
};
```